# ERROR: conflicting types for function, and previous declaration of function was here

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, function-prototypes

I am a very beginner level with coding. I have an error for each of my functions, my program is for a simple calculator and I'm still working on it, but I can't seem to get rid of the errors.

here are my prototypes

```
  int doubleInput (int *);
int squareInput (int *);
int cubeInput (int *);
```

and my functions

```
int *doubeInput (int* inputVal)
   {

      printf("%d x 2", inputVal); 

      return ("%d * 2",inputVal);
   }


  int *squareInput (int* inputVal)
   {

      printf("%d x %d", inputVal, inputVal);

      return ("%d * %d", inputVal, inputVal);

   }


  int *cubeInput (int* inputVal)
   {

      printf("%d ^ 3", inputVal);

      return ("%d * %d * %d", inputVal, inputVal, inputVal);
   }
```

The same error comes up for each function.

Comment: What difference do you see between `int doubleInput (int *)` and `int *doubeInput (int* inputVal)`?

Comment: the * before the doubleInput.

Comment: Okay, so remove it. That will fix the type conflict. You also have a typo in the function name. After that, you will find that `return ("%d * 2",inputVal);` does not do any arithmetic. To deal with that, you should use a C textbook or tutorial.

Comment: You also have undefined behaviour. Printing a pointer requires format specifier `"%p`, not `"%d"`. You probably want to print `*inputVal` instead of `inputVal` I suggest you should revisit the chapter about pointers in your tutorials.